# Bounded perfect-free sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are countable?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I refine the question, if $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and contains no nonempty perfect subsets, then $A$ must be countable? (Without denying the continuum hypothesis.)

Comment: Did you understand the answer to your earlier question? If you did, you now know how to construct Bernstein sets and can use the construction to answer your 2nd question.

Answer (score 2):

If the continuum hypothesis fails, then there is a subset of $[0,1]$ which does not include any perfect set of size $\aleph_1$.

If not, then the construction of Bernstein sets can be carried out within $[0,1]$. That is, we can construct a bounded Bernstein set within any interval. The construction is exactly the same as with the general case. In fact we can just make the following statement:

> Suppose that $\cal F$ is a family of perfect sets of real numbers, then there exists a set $A$ such that $\forall F\in\cal F$, $F\nsubseteq A$; and moreover we can require $A\subseteq\bigcup\cal F$.

Taking $\cal F$ to be all the perfect subsets of $[0,1]$ works out.

Comment: You can also use homeomorphism from an open interval to $R$. Image of a perfect subset will be again perfect and, hence, preimage of Bernstein set will give an example.

Comment: Or you can just take any Bernstein set and intersect with $[0,1]$ (for example), and you can prove that this intersection is a Bernstein set.